# Convert German Text into English using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to convert one table column from German to English using Oracle.
There are 10 lac record in the table so can't convert manually.

Comment: If you have a dictionary, use it. Otherwise, I don't think that Oracle will automagically translate "Hund" into "dog".

Comment: Oracle dose not have a translate package, but if you have some static message then you can create a table and store them with message_seq as an id and columns with English ,  German ... translations